# How to make a line break in Email?

Tags: javascript, email

So I have been making an email sender with this code:

```
                var link = "mailto:example@gmailcom"
                + "?cc=myCC@gmail.com"
                + "&subject=" + encodeURIComponent("Order")
                + "&body=" + encodeURIComponent("Some random send string <br>Some more send string")
                ;

            window.location.href = link;
```

However, the 
 tag does not work. Does anyone know how to make a line break?

Comment: Have you tried `\n`?

Comment: Also see [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_templates.asp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are encoding the break tag:

```
encodeURIComponent("Some random send string <br>Some more send string")
// 'Some%20random%20send%20string%20%3Cbr%3ESome%20more%20send%20string'
```

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. Whatever is receiving the mailto probably isn't interpreting the `<br>` as a line break. The encoding is actually correct but `<br>` should be a `\n`.